# Android permission gven only from a minimum sdk version onward

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-4.4-kitkat

Is it possible to declare a uses-permission for an app such that the permission is only given if the sdk version is at least a certain value?

I ask because I recently updated to KitKat (SDK Version 19) and to query for album art, one must now have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. But I don't want those updating the app to require a new permission just because those in 4.4 now require it...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't target KitKat, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

*"Over time, new restrictions may be added to the platform such that, in order to use certain APIs, your app must request a permission that it previously did not need. Because existing apps assume access to those APIs is freely available, Android may apply the new permission request to the app's manifest to avoid breaking the app on the new platform version. Android makes the decision as to whether an app might need the permission based on the value provided for the targetSdkVersion attribute. If the value is lower than the version in which the permission was added, then Android adds the permission."*

Comment: Hmm, Android suggests the opposite; from your link: _"Beware that .. your app listing on Google Play will show these required permissions even though your app might not actually require them.
To avoid this and remove the default permissions you don't need, always update your targetSdkVersion to be as high as possible."_

Comment: To me that says that a KitKat user would already have approved that permission, if the app is already installed with a < API 19 target so on upgrading they won't be prompted for further permissions. Likewise a < KitKat user won't be requested for new permissions as they're not required.